# Jenkins - Close the Jenkins job as soon as one of the parallel scrips fail

Tags: perl, jenkins, parallel-processing

I'm running two Perl scripts in parallel in Jenkins

```
some shell commands
perl script 1 &
perl script 2 &
wait
some more shell commands
```

If one of the perl scripts fail in the middle of the execution , the job waits until the other script runs (as it is executed in parallel in background).

I want the job to stop as soon as one of the script fails and not waste time by completing the execution of other script.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set up a signal handler for SIGCHLD, which is a signal that is always delivered to the parent process when a child exits. I'm not aware of a mechanism to see which child process exited, but you can save the subprocess process identifiers and just kill both of them when you receive SIGCHLD:

```
some shell commands
perl script 1 &
pid1=$!
perl script 2 &
pid2=$!
trap "kill $pid1 $pid2" CHLD
wait
some more shell commands
```

The script above has the downside that it will kill the other script regardless of the exit status of the subprocess. You could in the trap, if you want to, add a check for the exit status. The subprocess could e.g. create some temp file if it succeeds and the trap could check if the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Typically with Jenkins you would have the parallel steps running as separate jobs (or projects as they are sometimes known) rather than steps in a job. This would then allow the steps to run in parallel across different slave machines and it would keep the output for the jobs in a separate place.

You would then have a controlling job running the other parts.

I like the [Multijob](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) plugin for this sort of thing.

There are alternatives which may suit better, such as [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) which uses a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) to describe the jobs you want to run